# Manually installed plugin doesn't show up

Tags: plugins

I installed a plugin called hide-title by unzipping it and copying the files to the plugins dir. But it doesn't show up in the plugin list.

I've checked the following:

- the plugin's main php file looks fine at a glance, it has the required header
- there's no double nesting problem such as "plugins/hide-title/hide-title/..."
- I've tried chmod -R 777 wp-content
- The plugin is compatible with my wordpress version
- I'm not working in a wrong dir - I tried, for example, renaming the twentyten theme to twentyten_ and that got reflected in the dashboard

It seems to be a more general problem because I also tried installing a theme and got the same problem.

I don't want to install the stuff via the dashboard UI because I had FTP/permissions problems with that and gave up on it.

Comment: Does this happens in another WordPress install? Have you [troubleshooted](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list)? [Debugged](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it turns out that on ubuntu/debian, the wordpress files are in 3 places on the filesystem - /var/lib/wordpress, /srv/www/wp-content and /usr/share/wordpress. I had to do this for all three:

```
sudo chown -R www-data .
sudo chgrp -R www-data .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Works fine now. Even installation through the dashboard works now.

Comment: Good job for finding a solution. You should mark your answer as correct using the green tick